# Infinite loop in program written as an exercise about finding the value of Pi

Tags: c, approximate

I have this assignment

> The value of Pi can be determined by the following product
>
> ```
>          2 * 2   4 * 4   6 * 6               N * N
> Pi = 2 * ----- * ----- * ----- * ... * -----------------
>          1 * 3   3 * 5   5 * 7         (N - 1) * (N + 1)
> ```
>
> Write a C program that calculates the approximated value of Pi as long as the general term is greater than 1 + 10<sup>-9</sup>.

To solve it, I wrote this code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  double pi;
  const double End =
      1.0 + (1.0 / (10.0 * 10.0 * 10.0 * 10.0 * 10.0 * 10.0 * 10.0 * 10.0 * 10.0));
  double N = 2.0;

  pi = 2.0 * ((N * N) / ((N - 1.0) * (N + 1.0)));

  while (pi > End) {

    N += 2.0;
    pi *= ((N * N) / ((N - 1.0) * (N + 1.0)));
  }
  printf("%lf", pi);

  return 0;
}
```

I can't really understand how things work. I managed to use only `double` variables and added `.0` to all the number literals, but the program is stuck and doesn't give any value when I launch it.

Why?

Comment: Try printing the value of `pie` in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Just so you know, you can also write 10^-9 as 10e-9, rather than a long line

Comment: i think i know what's the problem now thanks to dbush , when i printf("%lf",pie); in the while loop , it turned out to be an infinite loop which indicates that there is a math problem  since pie will always be greater that 1+10e-9. I wonder now if i git the objective of the question wrong then

Comment: I think you are looking for the difference between your formula and the real value to be less than End.  Dont' forget to take absolute value of difference.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/5Sb7dCP  , a photo of the exercise question , how should i solve it then?

Comment: The "general term" is the value of each added iteration. Once the value of the iteration to be added is less than the limit, you should terminate the progression.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Not added, multiplied.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to keep track of the old value, and thus replace the loop to the following (needs <math.h>)

```
double pi_old = pi + 1e9; // initialize to large value
while (fabs(pi-pi_old) > End){
    pi_old = pi; // store this

    // then compute next
    N += 2.0;
    pi *= ((N * N) / ((N - 1.0) * (N + 1.0)));
}
```

Also, As I've commented,

```
const double End =
      1.0 + (1.0 / (10.0 * 10.0 * 10.0 * 10.0 * 10.0 * 10.0 * 10.0 * 10.0 * 10.0));
```

is equivalent to

```
const double End = 1.0 + ( 1.0e-9 );  // 1.0e-9 = 1.0*10^(-9)
```

Comment: `End` as correctly calculated by OP, is slightly larger than 1. `while (fabs(pi-pi_old) > End)` could end with Pi being 2.14 or 4.14. That is unlikely what the teacher expects. The required condition is targeting a factor, not an increment.

Answer (score 0):

This condition `while (pi > End)` does not match the requirements.
It will loop while the total product is larger than roughly 1, which for any approximiation of Pi will be an endless loop.
The decription refers to only the last part `(N*N)/( (N-1) * (N+1) )` being larger than 1 + a little.

So the solution is to calculate that last part separately and use only it in the loop condition.

(*I intentionally do not provide more details or code, because of

[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)* )